# R- Populating a dataframe based on another one with conditions

Tags: r

im new on R and i have a data set of 22x252, the 252 have many repeated values on column 1(ID). I made another dataset that has nrows of the unique values (with those values already populated), and i want to populate the rest of the columns based on the other dataset (basically summing all the values that share the same value in column 1.)

Is there a basic function that enables me to do this?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Sure, give me a few, im kinda new at this

Comment: Please, could you share a sample of your data and your expected output? And what have you done so far? Please review how to post code, it will help us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `aggregate` in `base R`.  Assuming the column name of first column is 'ID' and all other columns are numeric class, we group by 'ID' and get the `sum` of the rest of the columns in `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~ ID, df1, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Or with new version with `across`

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(-group_cols(), sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```